# How accurate is the reading for GPS in iPhone's SDK?

Tags: iphone

Using iPhone's SDK GPS API, how accurate can I get? Is it within a few meters or kilometers? I'm interested in the accuracy when it is indoor. **My software will only be used in door.**

Comment: If your software is primiarly used indoors then the GPS may not even come into play since GPS requires near line of sight to the satelites. Now it may work if they are near a window, but in this case you are going to typically only be getting location by cell tower proximity, and proximity to any known wifi access points.

Comment: You are right, so essentially I am asking how accurate can cell tower calculations get?

Comment: Not very, from what I've seen perhaps to ~500 meters. The main thing that will make it more accurate is proximity to WiFi that is in (Apple's? or AT&T's?) database, if you are near those then the range could be withen a hundred meters or less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best possible accuracy seems to be 9 meters. Common values (outdoor, good coverage) is 17 m, 23 m and 49 meters. With trees covering the sky you'll probably stay under a hundred meters, but hardly accurate enough for GIS or anything like that.

Comment: As a Geocacher, we see 17m (56') as about the best you can get.  Sometimes smaller, but this is rare.

Comment: S.Lott, are you saying this from your experience with the iPhone? You have an app that tells your geo location and it is only accurate to 17m?

Comment: As S.Lott says, that is the most common "best" value. The next step (9 m) happens, but is rare. And yes, this is from experience, there are a lot of applications that report raw data from the GPS unit that can show this. One (mine) is Glint.

Answer (score 3):

The API has a property or method that returns the current accuracy of the location measurement. If your goal is only to use the location if accuracy is within some limit then you should make sure that you check the returned accuracy, since the location may be only accurate to within a few thousand meters initially as its just using your location from the cell towers, and it will typically get better and better accuracy as the GPS powers up and starts getting a fix.

Comment: The property to check is called horizontalAccuracy:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW5

Answer (score 1):

Most standard GPS chips (and the iphone is that) can get around 10 meters accuracy.
Best results are outside on a clear sky obviously.

The difference between GPS chips is usually how quickly they can reception and how well they can hold it. Accuracy is pretty constant except for those using WAAS sattelite (which the iphone GPS doesn't do)

Answer (score -1):

Based on my own experience it's within meters.